# Bank annouced they're closing my local account when I told them I needed to change address to a relatives' prior to moving abroad

Tags: usa, germany, banking

I currently bank with an online bank out of Simple, or did until I told them I was moving to Europe, and wanted to change my address to reflect that.

They promptly told me that my account would be closed in 30 days. This seems insane to me. I need my account to pay the remainder of my lease which I'm locked into for an unknown amount of time (some time less than 4 months) and utilities.

Is the moral of the story to not mention why you're changing your address before moving abroad?

Edit: I am, in fact, a US citizen.

Comment: I see Simple is a US bank but you don't mention if you are a US citizen. They may have done that if they aren't set up to take and submit withholding tax, which they are required to do for a non-citizen non-resident. In that case you need a better bank.

Comment: Some accounts' terms and conditions include residency requirements. I'm technically in breach of my credit card's T&Cs, but they know my address and haven't cancelled the card so I'm not going to bring it up. However, it's not clear what practical benefit you could derive from the question as currently written, so I don't think it's [on topic](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: This is tagged both USA and Germany, can you clarify *from* where you are moving?

Comment: To clarify my close-vote: I do not see a question here, so I have voted to close as unclear what you are asking.